# Java, How does one re-cast an object based on one of its interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, casting

I have a set of classes that implements interfaces `Paintable` and `Tickable`.
Another class, `World`, keeps track of some of these classes by shoving them into an `ArrayList<Tickable>`.

I have a different class that works on all objects that are `Paintable`, and a sure way to get all of these objects is to ask world for this with a getPaintables() method, as all objects held by `World` are both tickable and paintable.

The probles arises from the from when I try to cast `Tickable` objects as `Paintable` ones like this:

```
    for (Paintable p : (ArrayList<Paintable>)world.getPaintables()) {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

This results in:

```
    error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Tickable> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Paintable>.
```

Is it possible to work around this by casting it some other way? I could, ofcourse duplicate the `ArrayList` in `World`, one as `Paintable`, and the other one as `Tickable`, but this seems cumbersome to me.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: The simplest thing would probably be to cast the individual objects, not the list as a whole.

Comment: They have to have a common base class and you could cast to that class then. You should read the [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) tutorial first.

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy They are alreaddy subclasses of different superclasses.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I was thinking that, but this causes problems further down when I need to call interface-specific methods.

Comment: @Jarmund, why?  Write `for (Tickable t : world.getPaintables()) { Paintable p = (Paintable) t; // do whatever you need to with p }`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman disregard, i mistyped the syntax when casting. Cheers!

Comment: @Jarmund Usualy you can implement most of the things without typecasting. When you need to iterate something in some object, use `Iterable<........>` interface  for every type you want to iterate and then you will not need typecast. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to "fix" this is just to create a common interface and use that for all your lists.  If all your classes implement both `Tickable` and `Paintable` as you say, you probably should be doing it this way anyway.

```
public class TickAndPaint
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<TickableAndPaintable> list = new ArrayList<>();
      for( Paintable t : list ) {
      }
      for( Tickable t : list ) {
      }
   }
}

interface Paintable {}
interface Tickable {}
interface TickableAndPaintable extends Paintable, Tickable {}
```

Comment: Somewhat bloated, but by far the cleanest approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need typecast at all. Implement `Iterable<Paintable>` and `Iterable<Tickable>` on `World` and then you can simply do either `for(Paintable p : world)` or `for(Tickable t : world)` Both will work without typecasting.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative that doesn't require changing the class / interface hierarchies, is to declare the `List` container in your `World` class with a [bounded type parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) having *multiple bounds*. For example:

```
class World<T extends Object & Paintable & Tickable> {

    private List<T> tickablePaintables = new ArrayList<>();

    /*...*/

    public List<T> getTickablePaintables() {
        return tickablePaintables;
    }
    /*...*/       
}
```

Then in the client code, you could iterate through the tickable-paintable list returned by `World` without casting:

```
public <T extends Object & Paintable & Tickable> void doSomething() {

    World<T> w = new World<>();

    for (Tickable tickable : w.getTickablePaintables()) {
        //...
    }            
    for (Paintable paintable : w.getTickablePaintables()) {
        //...
    }            
}
```

Due to the way type parameters work in Java, this will unfortunately add some clutter to the class/method declarations (for declaring `T`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question entirely, but I'll give it a try.

If world.getPaintables() returns List it's clear that your code does not work.

If world.getPaintables() holds both, the tickable and paintable objects one could do something like Louis said:

```
for (Object p : (ArrayList<Object>)world.getPaintables()) {
    if (p instanceof Paintable)
        paint();
    else if  (p instanceof Tickable)
        tick();
}
```

Comment: All objects returned are both Tickable and Paintable

Comment: Then you should do something like marspace suggested!

Answer (score 0):

What datatype does return world.getPaintables()?
If the return of that method is an ArrayList of Paintable, you should not cast anything.
Anyway, you could do something like:

```
for(Object p : world.getPaintables()) {
    if(p instanceOf Paintable){
       (Paintable)p ... (do something);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.